# Laravel 4.2 extend Session::put() method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4.2 project and we are having problems with sessions. If a ajax call gets sent out and takes a while to execute and in the mean time someone logs out, the ajax requests (since it completes after the logout happens) will refresh the session data and the user will be back in. There are several other issues, that are caused by exact scenario when session gets refreshed as well.

We are using database as our session driver.

I was thinking to write a custom driver, that will refresh the session data from database when before saving, but for that I need to extend the Session::put() method to find out what was actually added during that request lifetime.

I have been trying to extend the Session system, but there is a part of code that 
has hardcoded reference to Laravel's session middleware in …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Foundation/­Application.php

```
        $client = (new Builder)
                ->push('Illuminate\Cookie\Guard', $this['encrypter'])
                ->push('Illuminate\Cookie\Queue', $this['cookie'])
                ->push('Illuminate\Session\Middleware', $this['session'], $sessionReject);
```

So my question is if there is a way to extend the Session::put() method or even better if there is a solution for my initial problem? Any help Will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like bad application design so that's what you should fix, not the way that the session works. Requests need a long time to run should be deferred to [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) to avoid this issue.